# How to differentiate between similar phrases by using Regex

Tags: regex

Hi I am trying to match "Door Shelves" instead of "Freezer Door Shelves" in this table (left column shows features and right column shows values):

> Door Shelves                 4
>
> Freezer Door Shelves         1

I wrote the regex code

```
^Door Shelves\s*([\d.]*)
```

but it does not work... If I write

```
Door Shelves\s*([\d.]*)
```

it values returned will be 4; 1...

May I know what I should do?

Btw, I am writing this regex in import.io. Thanks!

Comment: What you mean, I'm writing that in import.io? what language you are working on?

Comment: First pattern with `^` seems to work just fine to me.  What language?  How are you getting the data?  One big chunk, or line by line, etc?

Comment: Before the editions... There wasn't the `*` in the second regex

Comment: Thanks guys. Import.io is a web scraping tool, and I am using it to scrape the product specifications from the website. I write regex in import.io to tell it what information I want from the website. In this case, I only want "door shelves" instead of "freezer door shelves." I get the data line by line I guess. So I'm not using any language, but just Regex...hope this is clear.

Comment: There is no "just regex". Every tool has its own regex language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^ only matches line beginning. My guess is that you have spaces at the start of the line. So ^ does not work.

```
Door Shelves\s*([\d.]*)
```

matches both cases. So the value returned is 4;1

Try this

```
[^r] Door Shelves\s*([\d.]*)
```

So it will not match the Freezer Door Shelves 1 case

But I would use xpath with impor.io. xpath is much more resiliant and reliable

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. May I know what [^r] means?

Comment: It means the "Door" word is NOT preceded by a "r"